# SVN : file names with special characters (éèà...)

Tags: svn, utf-8, character-encoding

We are working on Mac/Windows/Linux. Windows users have commited some files with name containing special characters using SVN under Eclipse. On MacOs, doing a fresh checkout (using command line), SVN is not able to match those directories/files.

```
$ svn co [...]
$ svn st
 ?      ShapeLibraries/Cahiers spéciaux
 !      ShapeLibraries/Cahiers spéciaux

[...]
```

Since files are UTF-8 encoded, i've looked at the string using latin-1, to see what  the char conversion would be :

[image]

The first string is malformed, while the second string is fine (UTF8 é == Latin1 Ã©)

Any idea what is causing this? Any solutions (other than renaming all the files without special characters)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned here and elsewhere, the root cause is as follows:
For some characters, UTF-8 allows different ways to encode them (composed vs. decomposed).
The file systems on macOS (HFS+ or APFS) encode filenames in the normalized decomposed form (NFD), while Subversion seems to use a different UTF-8 encoding when files are added.

So when a file named ä_¥_é_ç_Ø.txt is added from the command line:

```
> svn add ä_¥_é_ç_Ø.txt
A       ä_¥_é_ç_Ø.txt
```

Subversion stores the file name in a different encoding which leads to problems:

```
> svn status
?       ä_¥_é_ç_Ø.txt
!       ä_¥_é_ç_Ø.txt
```

The first line is about the existing file (whose name is NFD encoded). This file exists in the file system but is unknown to Subversion ("?").
The second line is about the added file (whose name is encoded differently). This file is known to Subversion but does not exist in the file system ("!")

To see the different encodings, use xxd:

```
> svn status | head -1 | xxd; echo; svn status | tail -1 | xxd
00000000: 3f20 2020 2020 2020 61cc 885f c2a5 5f65  ?       a.._.._e
00000010: cc81 5f63 cca7 5fc3 982e 7478 740a       .._c.._...txt.

00000000: 2120 2020 2020 2020 c3a4 5fc2 a55f c3a9  !       .._.._..
00000010: 5fc3 a75f c398 2e74 7874 0a              _.._...txt.
```

Here is how I deal with this to make Subversion work with UTF-8 encoded file names on macOS file systems:

When adding or removing files from Subversion, I do not type or autocomplete the file names in the Subversion command.
Instead I `ls` the file, copy the file name, and paste it into the Subversion command, where it will show up with the encoding's actual hex codes.
Doing this causes Subversion to use the actual file name encoding instead of using a converted form.

Example:

```
> svn status
?       ä_¥_é_ç_Ø.txt
> ls
ä_¥_é_ç_Ø.txt
```

Copy the file name and paste it into the following command

```
> svn add a<0308>_¥_e<0301>_c<0327>_Ø.txt
A         ä_¥_é_ç_Ø.txt
> svn commit -m "Test"
Füge hinzu         ä_¥_é_ç_Ø.txt
Übertrage Daten .erledigt
Übertrage Transaktion...
Revision 4 übertragen.
> svn status
>
```

Answer (score 1):

The two names are different Unicode codepoint sequences. Using JavaScript on the text in your question:

```
"é".codePointAt(0).toString(16)
> 65

"é".codePointAt(1).toString(16)
> 301
```

But

```
"é".codePointAt(0).toString(16)
> e9
```

U+0065 is LATIN SMALL e
U+0301 is COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
U+00E9 is LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE

They are semantically the same. Programs *should* compare them as the same. Try renaming one to the other throughout all references to it: repositories, local file systems, projects files, etc.